# How to type a generic `pick` function?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following function:

```
type TPick = {
    object: { [key: string]: any };
    keys: string[];
}
const pick = ({ object, keys }: TPick): { [key: string]: any } =>
    keys.reduce((obj, key) => {
        if (object && Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(object, key)) {
            obj[key] = object[key]
        }
        return obj
    }, {});

const data = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2
}

const { a } = pick({object: data, keys: ['a']})

console.log(a)
```

I've taken a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59934654/typescript-generic-type-for-pick-function-result-object-values-types) answer, but I don't really understand what's going on there.

The way I think I understand it, `object` will always be of type `{ [key: string]: any }`, because I'll never really know what kind of object is passed. Likewise, this function will also always return an object of type `{ [key: string]: any }`, due to the nature of `object` being unknown.

My question is, is it possible to type this any better than it currently is? TS is complaining about the `key` in

```
obj[key] = object[key]
    ^^^
```

and I'm not sure how to fix it.

I'm a little new to TS. In the above linked SO question, can I make use of,

```
export function pick<O, T extends keyof O>(keys: T[], obj?: O): Pick<O, T>;
export function pick<T>(keys: T[]): Mapper;
```

and if so, what do `O` and `T` represent?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgCgSwMYGsoF4oG8CwAoKQqAewCMArCJYALmygG0UIQ6BnYAJwQDsBzALp0AhjxBQAvgG58RKMxBt2XXnwYCZeCfiTEeHKGGRpMACiwkKVYABp5LNpLrxjASjoWmLZd35CoouISGAB8skQKbAB0nBAAJgCuSBCmpmTkdgquodjhcoQIAGZQaVbUUABkFVAA8mXAUWCcxMAt4BBRABbCbDUA7jxwzZCcoFFIwgA2k6WU1Jksrtm4BPlr6V4gAhiWc8CbAnn52qtrscAJnDy7RxJ2WBKumjp6BnHCwMI7K4TCdACMNnCpDoACZ8CcXvpgPQvsFMEZUOZ0tY6O9PgtFHQGAByYQ4gSPfBQtjESYdSbEPimYSuIA)

Comment: In other languages, `O` and `T` would be type placeholders for a generic function, a function that can handle "any" type so long as they match up in the specified places. In this case, `T` is an array of keys in an object `O`. It doesn't matter what the key types are specifically or how the object `O` is arranged, just that they are an array and an object.

Answer (score 0):

That is because `obj` is not just any object, but a partial of `object` that you're passing in. Since you didn't type the accumulator as such, this causes an error as you cannot simply access any arbitrary key in it.

Therefore, you will have to explicitly cast the type of the accumulator in your `Array.prototype.reduce` function as `Partial<typeof object>`:

```
keys.reduce((obj, key) => {
    if (object && Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(object, key)) {
        obj[key] = object[key]
    }
    return obj
}, {} as Partial<typeof object>); // <- This is the casting you need
```

See [error-free proof-of-concept on TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.0-beta&ssl=11&ssc=11&pln=11&pc=36#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgCgSwMYGsoF4oG8BQV9QD2ARgFYRLABc2UA2ihCDQM7ABOCAdgOYC6NAIZcQUAL4BuPAUYgWrDtx50%20UsTiSEubKGGRpMACixEyFYABoosluJrx9AShomGTBZ14Cow0WIwAfNL4NgB07BAAJgCuSBCGhiSkVrKOgdjBBPgIAGZQiWaUUABkxVAA8oXAoWDshMD14BChABaCLOUA7lxwdZDsoKFIggA2IwXklClMjmm4WQsESW4gfBimk8ArfJlZ6ov4EcDR7FwbmWJWWP7tUHCCAwijADygkIR5SeYBjlIaWjpIoJgIJ1vMfDQAIwWaTEGgAJhw6n%202mAtFB-kwelQxi%20lBoQJB0zkNDoAHJBGS%20GJHDgUSxCCNmiNCDxDIJHEA).

Comment: `Partial` means the result will have the same keys as the original but with all properties optional. While this can be a solution, we can do much better with `Pick`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same approach as in that other answer. `T` and `K` represent generic type parameters. Generic type parameters can either be explicitly specified when calling the function (ex `pick<{ a: number, b: string}, 'a'>(/* arguments*/)`, not usually recommended in TS) or they can be inferred by the compiler based on the arguments passed in (usually recommended and seen below). For `T` we don't really need any constraints it can be any type, for `K` we will constraing it to be a `keyof T` using `K extends keyof T`. You can read more about generics in typescript [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html)

```
const pick = <T, K extends keyof T>({ object, keys }: { object: T; keys: K[]; }): Pick<T, K> =>
    keys.reduce((obj, key) => {
        if (object && Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(object, key)) {
            obj[key] = object[key]
        }
        return obj
    }, {} as Pick<T, K>);

const data = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2
}

const { a, b } = pick({object: data, keys: ['a']}) //result has a, but b is an error

pick({object: data, keys: ['']}) // error '' is not a key of data
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKAxg9gdgzgLgAgA4EswGsEF4EB4AqANAgNIICmAHnOVACYwLrkCeEAZgvgHwAUA3gggAjAFbkwcYsxaMAvgC4EgkeMlL8AbiasYSkgG0AutrkBKJQAU06AsRLds3UAlc7ZAOgBO5OgFcwcl5eVWlWMydlFzcYlE4QsQlEADJkhAB5RMkPJC8IOHyWJHIPAAsAQxh0gHcoSzzirzgWDzBygBt2hLUpdzMI-miY4aExAxkjbFGe8dYjIeG5BZifOD8vKGmFuWJ+OQRKhGsMO1JuM01QUEhYRDpyuHKpwZBXcqUARkJo4SUAJlASxA12g8GUB2IwgQ+xwqAwAlUSSU90eYVkSgMAHJypijOYEAB6Ak+GB+dqICqMcqQvyIKEoKmbchePJeK4gOHoBFZODIh7U9x6BBY3H4okUFkQLwITGYhAMhBQfIHdxCTgop6gIA)

Answer (score -1):

Please try next example:

```js
type TPick<O extends unknown> = {
    object: O;
    keys: ReadonlyArray<keyof O>;
}

type Result<O, K extends keyof O> = {
    [P in K]: O[K]
}

const pick = <T,>({ object, keys }: TPick<T>) =>
    keys.reduce((obj, key) => {
        if (object && Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(object, key)) {
            return {
                ...obj,
                [key]:object[key]
            }
        }
        return obj
    }, {} as Result<T, keyof T>);

const data = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2
}

const { a } = pick({ object: data, keys: ['a'] }) // a: number
```

Please avoid mutating reduce accumulator